# Many-to-many in sqlalchemy. Preventing SQLAlchemy from inserting into a table if a tag already exists

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have a few ORM mapped tables, which (pared down) look like this:

```
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'

    tag_name = Column(String, primary_key=True)

task2tag_assoc = Table('tasktags', Base.metadata,
    Column('task_id', UUID, ForeignKey('tasks.task_id', ondelete='cascade'), 
           primary_key=True),
    Column('tag_name', String, ForeignKey('tags.tag_name', ondelete='cascade'),
           primary_key=True)
    )

class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'

    task_id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
    _tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=task2tag_assoc, backref='tasks',
            collection_class=set)
    tags = association_proxy('_tags', 'tag_name')

    def __init__(self, task_id, tags):
        self.task_id = task_id
        self.tags = set([tags])
```

With this setup, I can create a task with new tags just fine. It creates the tag
row in the `tags` table, and then creates the association to a new task just
fine in the `tasktags` table.

```
t = Task(task_id = uuid4(), tags=['foo', 'bar']) #this works
```

The problem comes when I try to create a task with a tag that already exists in
the `tags` table.

```
t2 = Task(task_oid = uuid4(), tags=['foo', 'baz']) #this will give an integrity error
```

It seems SQLAlchemy *always* tries to insert the tag into the tags table,
whether or not it already exists. I'd really like it to only create the
association if the tag already exists. This seems like it would be fairly normal
in many-to-many situations, but I can't find anywhere in the documentation
showing what I might be doing wrong.

Is there a way to get the behavior I want?

For background, I am using a postgresql 9.1 DB with the psycopg2 driver, and
SQLAlchemy 0.7.9 (Python 2.7.3)

Things I am considering as a last resort: Tags are technically a primary key and
nothing else, I could get away with just a task_id->tag table and no tags
table. But I'd like to be able to attach metadata to the tags themselves down
the road if it becomes necessary.

Comment: Search for "SQLAlchemy" and either "MERGE", "UPSERT", or "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE". The latter is MySQL syntax, the first two are the general names for what you want. It's surprisingly hard to get right, see http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/

Comment: This seems somewhat relevant, but I don't actually want it to update the tag row if it already exists, I just want it to skip that step and only add the tasktags row, which is a different table

Comment: Essentially, you want a feature like `INSERT ... IF NOT EXISTS`. That's much simpler; just `INSERT INTO tablename (tagname) SELECT 'newtag' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE tagname = 'newtag');` . There's still a race condition that can cause duplicate key errors, though, so you have to be prepared to handle them unless you're willing to `LOCK TABLE tablename IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` (serializing writes), which will do terrible things to performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the "unique tags only" recipe I usually use the unique object recipe, or some variant of it:  http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueObject.

This naturally requires a SELECT against a particular row in order to tell if it exists first.  The "upsert" technique, using database-specific commands to INSERT or UPDATE a row based on a database-side determination, is not directly supported by the ORM right now.   You're on Postgresql anyway which doesn't actually support any native "upsert" feature except one very awkward system using common table expressions.

Comment: So would it be accurate to consider these many-to-many relationship attributes as effectively read-only? Since you can't tell if it will fail without doing a separate query beforehand

Comment: not at all ? Task._tags, Task.tags etc. are freely mutable at any time.  This is just a creational pattern for a Tag object, has no bearing on the many-to-many table.

Comment: What can we do now that SQLAlchemy supports Postgres's ON CONFLICT "upsert?"

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete assoc links like this t2._tags = []

```python
t2 = Task(task_oid = uuid4())
t2._tags = []
tags = ['foo', 'baz']
for tag in tags:
    t2._tags.append(Tag(tag))
```